# Is it worthy to migrate quickfixj from Mina to Netty?

Tags: java, netty, apache-mina, quickfix

I am writing a FIX buyside GUI based on quickfixj. Although the performance is not an issue to a GUI, I am thinking of migrating the quickfixj from Mina to Netty as I would like to develop it to a buyside engine.  The performance of quickfixj is not satisfied with me. It is heard that Netty is better than Mina on performance.
Does anyone know is there any other opensource FIX engine on Java platform(because of many bugs in quickfixj)?I am wondering which one is a better choice, migration or another FIX engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how much perfomance gain you are expecting from implementing Netty rather than Mina in QuickfixJ. Sometimes we need to look at ease of adaption and maintainability rather than only perfomance. I implemented a fix engine using both quickfix and quickfixJ, the Java version was more complex in term of more messages being supported. Well the perfomance was more than was expected, went through around more than 300 messages/sec.

Regarding the QuickfixJ being buggy, yes it is, but you have the source code you can modify it as you want. I don't know of any other open source Java fix engine. And Quickfix is supported by vendors, if you intend to buy it they would be there to support any bugs in Quickfix.

I would prefer you modify it, I modified quite a lot of it to customize it for my use. If you have the resources there are lot of vendors who provide fix engines Cameron and Swift.

Comment: Yes, DC, I've been modifying quickfixj. I have applied a lot change to quickfixj v4, but found it's hard to apply the changes to the new version after quickfixj v5 is released. I even don't know which files are greatly different from the old version. It seems I have to stay in v4.

Comment: About the commercial FIX engine, my company is using Appia. Do you know the adv of Cameron and Swift to Appia?

Comment: @user462872 - To check the differences you can checkout their source code in svn and do a diff. I used it quite a lot. (http://www.fixprotocol.org/products/) - List of vendors who supply fix engines. Object Computing supports Quickfix, so you can get professional help, if you aren't able to modify Quickfix. It is very difficult to compare 2 producs unless you have used both of them. Best option is to google it.

Comment: Thank you for your information, DC.  I just do the modification when I need some feature or meet some issue.