# how can I process fix message quicker when sending through quickfixj

Tags: java, quickfix

I am having a problem with processing speed in QuickfixJ.  I read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831452/is-it-worthy-to-migrate-quickfixj-from-mina-to-netty) that its possible to process 300messages/sec.  I also saw elsewhere numbers reported in the thousands.  My Quickfix session code receives a list of messages and sends them one by one through Sesssion.SendToTarget();

It is possible that the loop in which I send the messages is slowing me down, but I was wondering is there a way to send a list of message or to speed up the process of sending these messages.  It may also be possible that because I am logging to the screen that this is slowing me down.  Would I benefit from running it headless and logging to just a file log?

Comment: I should have added that it appears to take between 20 and 50ms to between each log line from the toApp() method.  All toApp() does is write the outgoing message to the log.

Comment: 300messages/sec - Please don't take this number as a benchmark. The conditions under which I checked the throughput maybe quite different than yours.

Comment: It is not a benchmark, I saw that people reported elsewhere more than 2500messages a second, so I think that it is reasonable. To be honest I was hoping for between 750 and 1000.  I am glad you replied, I have a question specifically for you: when you say you processed 300msgs/sec, did you mean that you sent them or received them and dealt with them.

Comment: It was from end to end. Create, send and receive the acknowledgement/response from the other party, we were sending quotes and market data which might make it a bit slow because of the message size. The 2500 msgs/sec -> that looks very high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen QuickFIX/J processing messages in the thousands per second. However, you will have trouble getting that peformance in a single FIX session. The scenario I'm describing involved multiple sessions. The reason this is signficant is that the FIX protocol is inherently sequential per session due to the FIX sequence numbers. This effectively means you have one thread processing messages if you have one session. With multiple sessions, the engine can take advantage of multiple threads and processors.

Generally speaking, file I/O is the primary overhead. Look for ways to optimize the file system access. If you run the engine with no logging and a MemoryStore you'll see it is quite fast. I wouldn't use it for extreme low latency applications but it's not bad.

Answer (score 1):

Loging to the screen slow you down very much. With loging on the screen i was making like 30-40 messages per sec and whitout loging i`m making over 400. So simple do not display anything on the screen.
Also the slow part in the process is the answer from the Acceptor. The Initiator manage to send more then 2000 messages per second but the respond of the Acceptor is slowing down the overall process.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I was worried about my logging being and issue.  However I must log somewhere, surely logging to a file is just as slow?

Comment: QuickFix does loging on its own. If you like to  make your own additional loging you may think of some other way of calculating the time for the messages so the loging does not effect it. For example you can make orders by 1000 messages wich time you going to calculate then write all to the log (with paused timer) then resume timer and send another 1000 messages. I hope you can understand what i mean :)

Comment: for logging in general, considering that I log to a file and to the screen right now.  Would removing the logging to the screen have any effect on the speed if I am still logging to a file?

Comment: Removing the screen logging will increase the speed atleast 7-9 times. It slow down the process ALOT!

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating each message in the loop as that could be your overhead? This could be done asynchronously and then the messages sent as and when they are complete. Logging asynchronously would take away that additional overhead if you want to make sure that the sending time is minimized, just make sure to send any time data through to the logging thread so that it is accurate when logs get written.